# Assigning SELECT Results in Nested sql SELECT Statement to variables - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

In PHP-MySQL, I am using a nested select statement as follows:

```
SELECT object_id FROM form_entry WHERE id=(SELECT entry_id FROM form_entry_values WHERE value='32711178-888' AND field_id = (SELECT id FROM form_field WHERE name='dealer'))
```

Each SELECT returns only one cell as a result. However, I need each result of these SELECTs for example I need (depth 3):

```
SELECT id FROM oform_field WHERE name='dealer'
```

also I need (depth 2):

```
SELECT entry_id FROM form_entry_values WHERE value='32711178-888' AND field_id = (SELECT id FROM form_field WHERE name='dealer')
```

and I need (depth 1):

```
SELECT object_id FROM form_entry WHERE id=(SELECT entry_id FROM form_entry_values WHERE value='32711178-888' AND field_id = (SELECT id FROM form_field WHERE name='dealer'))
```

Is there any way to assign the results of these statements during **only one execution** of the largest SQL query (indicated as "depth 1")? In other words, without executing three sql queries, I am looking for a way assigning the results of the SELECT statements in each depth to a variable like $result_1, $result_2, etc.

It sounds there is no way to deal with it, but thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is equivalent with:

```
SELECT e.object_id
FROM form_entry e
  INNER JOIN form_entry_values v ON e.id=v.entry_id
  INNER JOIN form_field f ON v.field_id = f.id
WHERE v.value='32711178-888' 
  AND f.name='dealer'
```

and in this form the answer is straight forward: just add `v.entry_id` and `f.id` to the list of expressions in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT e.object_id, v.entry_id, f.id
FROM form_entry e
  INNER JOIN form_entry_values v ON e.id=v.entry_id
  INNER JOIN form_field f ON v.field_id = f.id
WHERE v.value='32711178-888' 
  AND f.name='dealer'
```

Comment: How could not I think of it? :) It is the solution I admire. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

try something like:

```
SELECT depth1.object_id, depth2.entry_id, depth3.id
FROM form_entry depth1
JOIN form_entry_values depth2 ON depth1.id=depth2.entry_id
JOIN form_field depth3 ON depth3.id=depth2.entry_id
WHERE
depth2.value='32711178-888'
AND depth3.name='dealer';
```